# Twitter data pull: How do i specify a range of date for Twitter data pull with specified keywords

Tags: python, api, twitter

How do I search and pull data from Twitter containg specific keywords (or search terms) and in a specific data range.

I see that I can use

```
import tweepy
#override tweepy.StreamListener to add logic to on_status
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener())
myStream.filter(track=['olympics'])
```

But here how do i specify the range of dates, like Jan 1 2016 to august 4, 2016,

Other way would be to use the api.searh

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(TwitterAuth.consumer_key, TwitterAuth.consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(TwitterAuth.access_token, TwitterAuth.access_token_secret)

rawParser = RawParser()
api = tweepy.API(auth_handler=auth, parser=rawParser)
result=api.search(count=100,q='olympics',result_type="recent")
```

Here ho do i pass the start date and stop date, and how to proceed if there is a list of keywords. I am using Python for programming.

Answer (score 0):

I searched in the web and found this library to be very useful https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python.

In Python,

```
tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch('olympics').setSince("2016-01-01").setUntil("2016-08-04").setMaxTweets(10000)
tweet = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)[0]

print tweet.text
```

Or,

```
python Exporter.py --querysearch 'olympics' --since 2016-01-01 --until 2016-08-04 --maxtweets 10000
```